# MariaDB Centos 6.5 mysql.libs conflics

Tags: centos6, mariadb

On our CentOS 6.5 no mysql was installed, but as dependency was automtaically installed  mysql-libs version: 5.1.73 Release: 3.el6_5.

Cannot we safely remove mysql-libs as we remove also dependencies. Is safe to replace mysql-libs with MariaDB one ?

Actual dependency from "yum remove mysql-libs":

Removing:

mysql-libs       x86_64   5.1.73-3.el6_5   @updates       4.0 M

Removing for dependencies:

cronie           x86_64   1.4.4-12.el6     @base          174 k

cronie-anacron   x86_64   1.4.4-12.el6     @base           43 k

crontabs         noarch   1.10-33.el6      @anaconda-CentOS-
201303020151.x86_64/6.4                                   2.4 k

munin            noarch   2.0.20-1.el6     @epel          534 k

munin-node       noarch   2.0.20-1.el6     @epel          1.3 M

postfix          x86_64   2:2.6.6-6.el6_5  @updates       9.7 M

sysstat          x86_64   9.0.4-22.el6     @base          824 k

Answer (score 3):

If it can help someone... we found this solution:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/centos-5x6x-mysql-lib-conflicts-and-postfix/

http://blog.johannes-beck.name/?p=199